# How do I put the XFS journal on another drive?

Tags: filesystems, xfs, mkfs

Trying to put the journal of a big hard drive on a smaller, but faster SSD.

```shellsession
$ sudo mkfs.xfs -N -l logdev=/mnt/data-journal/journal /dev/sdc
unable to get size of the log subvolume.
```

```shellsession
$ sudo mkfs.xfs -N -l logdev=/mnt/data-journal/journal,size=100m /dev/sdc
size 100m specified for log subvolume is too large, maximum is 0 blocks
```

```shellsession
$ sudo mkfs.xfs -N -l logdev=/mnt/data-journal/journal,size=0b /dev/sdc
Invalid value 0b for -l size option. Value is too small.
```

Bolded part is the really screwy up moment.

- It's a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
- `mkfs.xfs` version 5.13.0

**Edit:**

I have compiled from source and installed v6.2.0 of `xfsprogs`. The bug is still present. Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but the big drive has 4K sectors, while the small one has 512. (Trust me on those numbers.)

**Edit2:**

After getting past that error, another one cropped up when mounting the created filesystem:

```
/mnt/data: the kernel does not recognize /dev/sdb1 as a block device; maybe "modprobe driver" is necessary.
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The solution turned out to be so silly in the end!</s>

1. **The file needs to be pre-allocated.**

`truncate -s 100m /mnt/data-journal/journal`

I got a hint when I looked through the source code of `mkfs.xfs`. It opens the file or device and then issues an `ioctl` call with the file descriptor and `BLKGETSIZE`. And I'm like... *wait a minute*. I am *very new* to linux so this sort of thing was not at all obvious to me.

(I can't mount it for some reason, because of course there has to be another problem. But hey, it created it at least.)

---

Edit: The saga continues!

Preallocating the file certainly allowed me to get past that error. However I am unable to mount the filesystem now.

The error I receive is:
 `/mnt/data: the kernel does not recognize /dev/sdb1 as a block device; maybe "modprobe driver" is necessary.`

After experimentation, I was able to mount the FS if the journal is a device: e.g. `/dev/sdc`, but not if it's a file residing on another filesystem.

***Therefore the question is still open.***

Comment: It wants a *device*, not a file for the external journal. If you want to use a file then use losetup to make the file in to a device then use that (eg. /dev/loopXX) as the log device. Also look in dmesg for information on the errors generated because what mkfs and similar print out is often not the real problem.